# How to submit a page with WebClient setting the certificate or keystore?

Tags: java, certificate, keystore

I would like to click in a sumbmit button, but I don´t know how to set a certificate or cacerts into a webclient.

I´m using com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.

```
WebClient webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.getDefault());
HtmlPage htmlPage = webClient.getPage(urlPost);
HtmlForm form = htmlPage.getForms().get(0);
form.getInputByName("inputLogin").setValueAttribute("login");
form.getInputByName("inputPass").setValueAttribute("passwd");
HtmlPage subm = form.getInputByName("button1").click();
```

I don´t know how to do it, but I´m trying with

setSSLClientProtocols

```
subm.getWebClient().getOptions().setSSLClientProtocols(sslClientProtocols);
```

or setCredentialsProvider

```
subm.getWebClient().setCredentialsProvider(credentialsProvider);
```